# Python. Regular expressions. Получить слово в многострочном тексте

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения

Я уже задавался подобным вопросом, но тут немного другое. Есть текст с зарезервированными словами (например, BOLD, ITALIC, UNDERLINE, START, END и т.д). Между ними есть текст, который нужно получить.

`string = '''
BOLD
Some text
END
'''`

Если я использую регулярные выражения:

`reText = re.findall(r'[A-Z]\n(.*?)\n[A-Z]',string)
rePrefix = re.findall(r'[A-Z].*',string)
print(rePrefix[0],reText,rePrefix[-1])`

то текст выводится корректно. Если же я добавляю пробел(ы):

`string = '''`

`BOLD`

`Some text`

`END'''`

То текст (*some text*) не выводится.

Как поступить, учитывая, что

Comment: Под пробелами вы подразумеваете пустые строки?

Comment: @mkkik Да, они игнорируются и текст между зарезервированными словами не выводится.

Comment: `re.findall(r'[A-Z]\n+(.*?)\n+[A-Z]', string)`

Comment: @mkkik А если я добавляю в текстовое поле ещё дополнительные строки? 
`BOLD

Some text
Another text
Text
Text again

END`

Comment: Я не специалист по RE, но, мне кажется, что в таком случае вам надо шаблоны `[A-Z]` заменять на явное множество зарезервированных слов.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Следующий код работает:

```
>>> import re
>>> re_text = re.compile(r'^([A-Z]+)\n+(.*?)\n+([A-Z]+)$', re.M | re.S).findall
>>> re_text(string)
[('BOLD', 'Some text', 'END')]
```

Здесь флаг re.M - указывает на то, что строка многострочная - внутри есть символы перевода строки, а флаг re.S указывает что символ `.` интерпретируется как любой символ *включая* символы перевода строки.
Да, вместо первой и последней группы можно подставить набор валидных ключевых слов, тогда регулярка не споткнётся, если в тексте вдруг появится  слово из заглавных букв стоящее в отдельной строке.

Comment: Погоди, он выводит и BOLD и END. Мне нужно, чтобы вывел лишь текст между этими словами. Или мне вывести с помощью: `re_text(string)[0], re_text(string)[-1]?`

Comment: Он выводит список троек. в каждой тройки префикс, текст и постфикс.
`parsed = re_text(string); first_pref, first_text, first_post = parsed[0]`

Comment: А ключевые слова лучше брать из словаря?

Comment: И, к примеру, если после *END* будет ещё такой же блок (и т.д)? Как тут поступить?

Comment: В общем случае, не обязательно `re.M` использовать даже если regex содержит `\n`, если нет желания смысл `^$` изменять.

Comment: В данном случае флаг `re.M` как раз нужен - насколько я понял, предполагается что полный текст состоит из нескольких таких отрывков.